# django after successful login redirection to home it shows anonymoususer

Tags: django-views

```
def loggin(req):
    if req.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    if req.POST:
        username=req.POST['username']
        password=req.POST['password']
        usr = authenticate(req,username=username,password=password)
        if usr is not None:
            login(req,usr)
            return redirect('home')
    return render(req,'cart/login.html')

def home(req):
    print(req.user.name)
    return render(req,'cart/home.html')
```

my settings.py is fine, i have used reverse in redirect to view although in loggin function my user is logged in fine but as i want user info in home it shows error.I dont know what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.user` is a `User` object, and has no `.name` attribute, but a `.username` attribute, so:

```
def home(req):
    print(req.user.username)
    return render(req,'cart/home.html')
```

Since the `__str__` method also returns the username, it might be more convenient to print the `req.user`:

```
def home(req):
    print(req.user)
    return render(req,'cart/home.html')
```

---

> **Note**: In Django the first parameter of a function-based view is usually `request`, not <s>`req`</s>.